# PyTorch CUDA GPU not utilized properly

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu

I am trying to train a pytorch model on my local machine. It has the following GPUs:

[image]

As you see the second is NVIDIA and thus should be used with CUDA. In fact if I check `torch.cuda.device_count()` it returns 1 and `torch.cuda.get_device_name()` returns `NVIDIA GeForce 930MX`. When I run the script however the usage of the built-in Intel GPU goes up to 100% and then the program crashes with:

```
OSError: [WinError 1450] Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service
```

The usage (as seen from the task manager) of the targeted GPU (NVIDIA) remains 0% so it has not been called.

What configuration steps I might have messed up and what would you propose in order to run PyTorch on the proper GPU.

*Using the LTS versions of torch and CUDA as of the day of posting the question.

Comment: You need to pass the specific device name to your `torch` functions.

Comment: curious, did you try running the `nvidia-smi` command?